# Unable to boot Windows 10 despite running boot-repair in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair, grub-efi

I used boot repair's 'Recommended Repair' within ubuntu to fix the grub and boot issue of Windows 10 OS on an Alienware 15 R2, which fixed only the grub.
**Pastebin link generated by boot repair:**
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/McxnKhGHzJ/
**Drives in the PC:**
1) SSD (~240GB) >> Contains Windows and C: drive.
2) HDD (1TB) >> Contains 500GB D: drive for Windows files and the rest is divided into:
a) ~230GB for Ubuntu
b) ~230GB for my files etc.
c) 16GB swap space
d) 256MB EFI system partition

Post Ubuntu installation, the grub menu was not to be found and Ubuntu loaded directly on startup.
On restarting, I entered Windows via the boot menu (F12 key), which worked normally.
I came across this [link](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/) to enable the grub menu.
I executed the following command (in the cmd as an admin):

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

I observed that Ubuntu loaded directly on startup, despite the above step.
This time around Windows couldn't be accessed via the Boot menu (grub didn't work either) and gave this error:

```
The selected boot device failed. Press any key to restart.
```

I tried updating grub from within Ubuntu, changing UEFI to Legacy in system setup & disabling Secure Boot to no avail.
I **used boot repair** and the **grub menu can be seen now**, although whenever I click on a**ny Windows option** in the grub I either get this **error**:
[Windows 10 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdani.jpg)

**OR**
I see the Windows Recovery Options as follows (which do not help that much):
[Windows Reovery Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEUDs.jpg)
[Windows Advanced Recovery Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYgLB.jpg)
I have also executed the following commands using the cmd (in advanced recovery options):

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

The first command returns success, but doesn't help gain access to Windows. The second command returns not found.
**The grub menu is accessible after using boot repair (Windows entries don't work):**
[Grub Works after boot-repair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifv5I.jpg)
**My HDD partitions (sudo fdisk -l):**
[HDD partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkgvN.png)

**Boot-info report (after using boot-repair):** http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fxtxR4qZMq/

Comment: Wait, how is this a _Ubuntu_ question? I mean sure, you have Ubuntu installed. So have I, but I'm not posting my Windows _or_ Linux questions on [Vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com) merely on account of having Vim installed on Windows and Linux ...

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing the error message `The selected boot device failed. Press any key to restart.`
 because the bootmgr configuration change you made is invalid.

Resetting it to the correct value shouldn't be too hard via the *Repair Utilities* in the *Windows 10 Installer*, however setting up a bootable Windows 10 USB drive might take 30-40 minutes.

1. Visit the Windows 10 download site, and download a Windows 10 ISO
2. Make a Bootable Windows 10 USB drive from the ISO
3. Reboot the computer and press `F12` to enter the boot menu
4. Boot into the Windows 10 Installer via the USB Drive.
5. The prompt will ask you to begin installing Windows. Click *"ok"* to enter the setup. You won't be installing Windows, but there should be a "*let's get started screen*" before you can proceed to the repair utility.
6. From the installer menu, pick *Windows Repair*
7. You'll have a list of utilities, open *command prompt*
8. You need to undo the configuration change made earlier. Run `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`

Once that value is fixed, you should be able to boot back into Windows.

Next you will want to configure your machine to boot into Windows or Ubuntu by default and the other as secondary. This should allow you to press `f12` during boot and pick the secondary option whenever you want to boot there. You can do that via the Bios, `f2`.